# Php Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' ;

Tags: laravel, lumen, lumen-5.4

I am working on Lumen but why PHP artisan command is not working.

here are my commands those i ran:

```
~$: php artisan migrate:install
Migration table created successfully.
-$: php artisan make:migration --create=users create_users_table  
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','
```

Comment: Show your migration file. There must be extra , in code

Comment: but artisan command is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is due to this change - [Git Commit History](https://github.com/Naveen-Gupta/lumen/commit/78c6f18cd4b43531bf468b5933921a1fd91f5196#diff-7e3ce459dfcc113722bdf4667ceffc11R14)

Change the route in web.php back to:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
  return $app->version();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be a typo, probably on migration file. Show your code here or on git. And write like this  php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it is not working too.Here is mycode on github https://github.com/Naveen-Gupta/lumen.git